# Assembly debugging issue

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering

So I have the assembly code below and the goal is to run the code without hitting the explode bomb call. The user enters 6 numbers with spaces in between but that part isn't too important as it is mostly handled by the read six numbers function which is known to be good and not explode the bomb.

```
   0x0000000000400f0c <+0>:    push   %rbp
   0x0000000000400f0d <+1>:    push   %rbx
   0x0000000000400f0e <+2>:    sub    $0x28,%rsp
   0x0000000000400f12 <+6>:    mov    %rsp,%rsi
   0x0000000000400f15 <+9>:    callq  0x4015da <read_six_numbers>
   0x0000000000400f1a <+14>: cmpl   $0x0,(%rsp)
   0x0000000000400f1e <+18>: jne    0x400f27 <phase_2+27>
   0x0000000000400f20 <+20>: cmpl   $0x1,0x4(%rsp)
   0x0000000000400f25 <+25>: je     0x400f48 <phase_2+60>
   0x0000000000400f27 <+27>: callq  0x4015a4 <explode_bomb>
   0x0000000000400f2c <+32>: jmp    0x400f48 <phase_2+60>
   0x0000000000400f2e <+34>: mov    -0x8(%rbx),%eax
   0x0000000000400f31 <+37>: add    -0x4(%rbx),%eax
   0x0000000000400f34 <+40>: cmp    %eax,(%rbx)
   0x0000000000400f36 <+42>: je     0x400f3d <phase_2+49>
   0x0000000000400f38 <+44>: callq  0x4015a4 <explode_bomb>
   0x0000000000400f3d <+49>: add    $0x4,%rbx
   0x0000000000400f41 <+53>: cmp    %rbp,%rbx
   0x0000000000400f44 <+56>: jne    0x400f2e <phase_2+34>
   0x0000000000400f46 <+58>: jmp    0x400f54 <phase_2+72>
   0x0000000000400f48 <+60>: lea    0x8(%rsp),%rbx
   0x0000000000400f4d <+65>: lea    0x18(%rsp),%rbp
   0x0000000000400f52 <+70>: jmp    0x400f2e <phase_2+34>
   0x0000000000400f54 <+72>: add    $0x28,%rsp
   0x0000000000400f58 <+76>: pop    %rbx
   0x0000000000400f59 <+77>: pop    %rbp
   0x0000000000400f5a <+78>: retq
```

I know that the read 6 numbers part works fine and doesnt set off the bomb. All it does is get the input.

Hey I'm not real good at assembly but I'm working on this and I think I've figured out the first number is 0 and the second is 1 but that could be wrong. I see the comparison on line +14 but im not sure if thats comparing the first value or just making sure that the string the user entered wasnt empty. I know you're supposed to put in 6 numbers and that's only the first  2 though. I'm a bit confused about what lines +34 to +40 do. I get that that's where the compared numbers change but I'm not sure how it affects them. If anyone is good with assembly and can help me out that would be awesome.

Comment: Well that's one step better than last time :) As for the +34 ... do you understand what `mov`, `add` and `cmp` do? Since you mentioned debugging, have you tried running in a debugger? What did you see at those instructions?

Comment: I get rsp as a massive number which is where I get completely lost as I don't get how it works. I understand what the functions themselves do but I don't get where rbx comes from.

Comment: `rsp` is the stack pointer. In the debugger you don't want to look at `rsp` itself, you want to look at memory at address `rsp`. Look at line +6. That's where your inputs will be stored (4 bytes each). Then look at +25 and where it goes if the first two numbers check out.

Comment: ok I see that but I still don't quite get where %rbx comes into the picture. Based off of line  34 and 37 it looks like it increments by adding itself and previous input. It looks like it sets the 2nd to last input as %eax and then adds the last input. To me it looks like this is basically looking for the fibinaci numbers so 0 1 1 2 3 5 or am I reading that wrong ?

Comment: That is correct.